# Tiny JavaScript live filter

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for feedback on this live-filter I wrote in JavaScript. You can test it using the included snippet.

```js
(function() {
  var searchField = document.getElementById('filter');

  var handler = function() {
    var text = searchField.value,
      nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('phase'),
      regexp = new RegExp(text, 'i');

    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      var node = nodes[i];

      node.text.search(regexp) < 0 ?
        node.parentNode.style.display = 'none' :
        node.parentNode.style.display = 'block';
    }
  };

  searchField.onkeyup = handler;
  searchField.onchange = handler;
})();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="filter" />
<ul id="list">
  <li><a class="phase">Ruby on Rails</a></li>
  <li><a class="phase">The Rails Way</a></li>
  <li><a class="phase">Pickaxe Guide</a></li>
  <li><a class="phase">jQuery HTML</a></li>
  <li><a class="phase">CSS HTML AJAX</a></li>
  <li><a class="phase">HTML5 Net Set</a></li>
  <li><a class="phase">Node Easy</a></li>
  <li><a class="phase">Listing Bloop</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, a few notes:

- Your filtering is too broad. If you had other elements in the DOM with class `phase`, they would also be filtered, even though they aren't part of the list. Instead, it's better to limit what you're selecting -- DOM elements have `querySelectorAll`, `getElementsBy...`, etc., to ensure that you're limiting the results to that element's children.
- This can't be re-used very well -- make it more modular. You can do this by passing in the ID of the search field and the list (and any additional selectors).
- I'd suggest using classes to toggle visibility, because at some point you might actually want the styling to be different. Note that `classList` is only available on modern browsers (http://caniuse.com/#feat=classlist).
- Cache your lengths when iterating over an Array-like.
- There's no need for `parentNode` if you use `textContent`. Then you can query for all `li`s in the list and filter them instead. This also means you don't have to add classes for each list item unless you want to. In my example, I've removed the `class='phase'` portion of your anchors.
- I assume your items are eventually going to be links to elsewhere, so I left the anchors in the example.

```js
var liveFilter = (function() {
  /**
   * Initializes a search field with associated list and filters it live while typing
   *
   * @param {string} searchFieldId     An ID of a search field input element
   * @param {string} listId            An ID of an element containing items that should be filtered
   * @param {object} [options]         Specifies additional options:
   *                                   * selector: specifies a query to be run against list; the results
   *                                     will be filtered according to the value of the search field. If
   *                                     not specified, the filter matches all direct children.
   *                                   * filterClass: specifies a class name to be applied to items that
   *                                     are going to be filtered out. If not specified, defaults to
   *                                     "filter-hidden".
   */
  function liveFilter( searchFieldId, listId, options) {
    
    var searchField = document.getElementById(searchFieldId),
        list = document.getElementById(listId),
        selector,
        filterClass;
    
    if (!searchField) {
      throw new Error("No search element found with id " + searchFieldId);
    }
    
    if (!list) {
      throw new Error("No list element found with id " + listId);
    }
    
    if (options !== undefined) {
      selector = options.selector;
      filterClass = options.filterClass;
    }
        
    if (filterClass === undefined) {
      filterClass = "filter-hidden";
    }

    var handler = function searchFieldChanged() {
      var text = this.value,     // this will be bound to the search field
          regexp = RegExp(text, 'i'),
          nodes = (selector === undefined) ? list.children 
                                           : list.querySelectorAll(selector),
          node;
      for (var i = 0, l = nodes.length; i < l; i++) {
        node = nodes[i];
        if (node.textContent.search(regexp) < 0) {
          // note: classList is only available on modern browsers
          node.classList.add(filterClass);
        } else {
          node.classList.remove(filterClass);
        }
      }
    };

    // input is for modern browsers
    searchField.addEventListener("input", handler, false);
  }
  
  // If using CommonJS, you'd do module.exports = liveFilter, and it could be required later.
  return liveFilter;
})();

liveFilter("filter", "list", { selector: "li", filterClass: "filter-hidden" });
```

```css
.filter-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="filter" />
<ul id="list">
  <li><a>Ruby on Rails</a></li>
  <li><a>The Rails Way</a></li>
  <li><a>Pickaxe Guide</a></li>
  <li><a>jQuery HTML</a></li>
  <li><a>CSS HTML AJAX</a></li>
  <li><a>HTML5 Net Set</a></li>
  <li><a>Node Easy</a></li>
  <li><a>Listing Bloop</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

A few comments:

1)  You don't need the `new` keyword to use `RegExp`:

```
regexp = RegExp(text, 'i');
```

2) The ternary operator can be used as an expression anywhere, such as an assignment. Use `textContent` instead of `text`. Then you can use the regex `test` method which returns a boolean:

```
node.parentNode.style.display = node.textContent.test(regexp) ? 'block' : 'none';
```

Since this becomes a bit too long of a line, it would be better to cache the condition:

```
var mustShow = regexp.test(node.textContent);
node.parentNode.style.display = mustShow ? 'block' : 'none';
```

4) Finally, use `addEventListener` instead of the `onevent` properties. If you don't need to support ancient browsers, use the `input` event:

```
searchField.addEventListener('input', handler);
```

With a couple more edits, this is how it would look like:

```
;(function() {
  var searchField = document.getElementById('filter');

  var handler = function() {
    var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('phase'),
        regexp = RegExp(searchField.value, 'i');

    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
      var node = nodes[i];
      var mustShow = regexp.test(node.textContent);
      node.parentNode.style.display = mustShow ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
  };

  searchField.addEventListener('input', handler);
}());
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't help but find my code ad hoc. And there are other places I would like to apply the same function. A jQuery plugin not withstanding, what kind of pattern would you recommend? Turn this into an object that receives an element? A module pattern? I have no experience with JavaScript design patterns, but I want to learn them. I just haven't formed a mental model yet of how a design pattern would apply here.